# Having Problems with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

This script removes all the text from my button and makes it a green block.

```js
function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("musicButton").innerHTML =
    "<embed src=\"" + soundfile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

```html
<button id="musicButton" class="button" type="button" name="music" onmouseover="playSound('MySong.wav')">Hover Me For Sick Beats!</button>
```

Comment: I think fundamentally this is wrong. Don't set an embed as the inner html of a button. Why not wrap the button in a container element, then hide the button and append the embed to the parent wrapper?

Comment: Setting the `.innerHTML` property of an element (in this case your button) will *overwrite* it's contents.

Comment: I am very new to js, so i don't really understand..

Comment: You are taking a button with some text and replacing that text with the audio element. Don't do that. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eliminates the need to have any HTML element.

```js
function playSound(soundfile) {
  var audio = new Audio(soundfile);
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button id="musicButton" class="button" type="button" name="music" onmouseover="playSound('MySong.wav')">Hover Me For Sick Beats!</button>
```